# WPF Hot Reload works in .NET 4.8 app but not .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, hot-reload

I have a .NET application that can be built for both 4.8 and 6.0 but hot reload only works in the 4.8 version of the application.

Does anyone know what could be going on or the steps that i could take to resolve this?

I went through the [troubleshooting tips](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/xaml-hot-reload-troubleshooting?view=vs-2022) and ensured that the environment variable was set for both builds at runtime. Also, my window has the 'Hot Reload available' badge with ok status. Something weird that i noticed is that i dont get Hot Reload output in 4.8 but Hot Reload is working. But inn .NET 6, i get the following Hot Reload output:

```
16:18 15.28 Cboe.Raptor.UI.Launcher (20): Hot Reload session started.

16:18 36.94 Cboe.Raptor.UI.Launcher (20):45960: The process has exited.

16:18 36.94 Cboe.Raptor.UI.Launcher (20): Hot Reload session complete.
```

but Hot Reload is not working.

I initially suspected that Hot Reload doesn't like some assembly but this project is too large for handchecking to be feasible.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio do you use? Because the version before 22 did have hot reload features, but not as complete as the 22 version, if your Visual Studio is an older version, I suggest you update and see if there will be any situation you described.

Comment: I am using VS 2022

Comment: Hi,@CbJMartin.  Are you trying to create a new .NET 6 project to test if Hot Reload is working properly?  If the new project Reload doesn't work either, could you show minimal sample code that can reproduce the problem?  Did you add any Nuget packages to your project?  I would also like to know what is the version of your Visual Studio 2022?

Comment: sorry for the delay, for some reason my company had stackoverflow blocked for a while. as far as this issue goes, if i switch the order of the targetframeworks in the csproj from 
    <TargetFrameworks>net48;net6.0-windows</TargetFrameworks> to
    <TargetFrameworks>net6.0-windows;net48</TargetFrameworks> the problem goes to the last framework in the list. so before it wouldnt work for .net 6 after the switch it wont work for .net 4.8.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using WPF + .NET 6 and I was having the same problem (no hot reload, although without your error messages).

I just had to comment out `<PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>` in my .csproj file and everything went back to normal.

[Hao Yu-MSFT's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74486003/5480409) reminded me I had too an app-wide setting and I tried commenting them all one-by-one :D

Comment: I am unable to use this as we dont have this setting in our csproj files

Comment: @CbJMartin may I ask what's your Visual Studio version (number and edition, e.g. 17.4.0 professional, enterprise...), how many projects in your solution and what's in your *.csproj inside <PropertyGroup>...</PropertyGroup>?